# Como selecionar colunas em que anos são iguais no Oracle?

Tags: oracle, select

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada de `Clientes`, e nela eu tenho as seguintes colunas :

```
id_cliente
nm_cliente
dt_nascimento
```

Eu preciso selecionar e contar todos os clientes que nasceram no mesmo ano. Eu já tentei algumas coisas, mas elas não retornam com base do mesmo ano e sim do mesmo dia, mês e ano.

Meu query atual em que não está funcionando está assim :

```
SELECT dt_nascimento, count(*) FROM clientes
WHERE dt_nascimento = dt_nascimento
GROUP by dt_nascimento;
```

Como posso selecionar somente com base pelo mesmo ano ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem que extrair o ano do campo de data com a função [extract](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm), pode utilizar esta *query*:

```
SELECT  EXTRACT(year FROM dt_nascimento) as ano, count(*) as quantidade
FROM clientes
GROUP by EXTRACT(year FROM dt_nascimento);
```

Veja o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela resposta. Ele parece funcionar, mas está me retornando de que está faltando uma expressão.

Comment: Estranho, para ambos ele disse que são formatos inválidos. Por que está acontecendo isto ?

Comment: Funcionou certinho agora, +1 e resposta certa. Obrigado pela paciência em  corrigir a resposta.